# Salvar conteúdo de uma div em um arquivo .html Com php ou javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf, div

Como faço para salvar conteúdo de uma div em um arquivo .html Com php ou javascript.

A intenção é gerar um pdf posteriormente com esse html salvo. Vi que tem muitos tópicos aqui sobre o assunto, mas estou falhando miseravelmente, nenhum deles me ajudou, pois preciso salvar antes este html.

Obrigado

Comment: Salvar como? Pega o conteudo da div e salva aonde? no servidor como pagina HTML?

Comment: Isso, simplesmente salvar em um arquivo .html qualquer dentro do servidor mesmo.

Comment: Outra coisa, esse div está em outra pagina?

Comment: Está na mesma página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

pega o conteúdo da `<div class="publicar">` e joga dentro do `<textarea id="qqID"...` para poder ser enviado via post para o PHP

```
function CopiaDivParaTextArea()
{
   var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
   var conteudoParaPublicar = "";
   var pattern = new RegExp("publicar");

   for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
     if(pattern.test(divs[i].className)){
       conteudoParaPublicar += (divs[i].innerHTML || divs[i].textContent);
     }
   }
 document.getElementById("qqID").value = conteudoParaPublicar;
 document.formulario.submit();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="publicar"> <p>Este conteudo será salvo em uma pagina no servidor</p></div>
<div class=""> <p>Este conteudo NÃO será salvo pois a class não é "publicar"</p></div>
<div class="publicar"> <p>Este tambem será publicado na página</p></div>

<form name="formulario" action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="qqID" name="qqnome" style="display:none"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="CopiaDivParaTextArea();" />Publicar</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['qqnome'])){

    $conteudo = $_POST['qqnome'];
    //gera um numero aleatorio para concatenar com o nome do arquivo
    $num = mt_rand();

    //echo "nome do arquivo publicado: pagina".$num.".html";

    //salva o arquivo no servidor
    file_put_contents("pagina".$num.".html", $conteudo);

}
```

> **A seguir um teste da parte em que a div é passada para o textarea**

```js
    function CopiaDivParaTextArea()
    {
       var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
       var conteudoParaPublicar = "";
       var pattern = new RegExp("publicar");

       for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
         if(pattern.test(divs[i].className)){
           conteudoParaPublicar += (divs[i].innerHTML || divs[i].textContent);
         }
       }
     document.getElementById("qqID").value = conteudoParaPublicar;
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="CopiaDivParaTextArea();" />Testar</button>
 <div class="publicar"> <span>Este conteudo será salvo em uma pagina no servidor</span></div>
 <div class="">Este conteudo NÃO será salvo pois a class não é "publicar"</div>
 <div class="publicar"><span style="color:red">Este também será publicado na página</span></div>

 <textarea id="qqID" name="qqnome" rows="4" cols="47"></textarea>
```

Comment: Conhece uma tabela gaga? Confira aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308044/8063

Answer (score 1):

Há várias formas, uma delas é com a função [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php) nativa do php:

```
$fp = fopen('data.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<div>texto');
fwrite($fp, '<br>mais texto</div>');
fclose($fp);
```

O conteúdo de data.html agora é `<div>texto<br>mais texto</div>`

Se o servidor estiver em um linux pode usar a função [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) para executar algo como:

```
exec("echo '<div>texto' >> data.html");
exec("echo '<br>mais texto</div>' >> data.html");
// Ou
exec("echo '<div>texto<br>mais texto</div>' > data.html");
```

A diferença entre `>` e `>>`, é que o primeiro apenas sobrescreve o que estiver dentro do arquivo, já o segundo, adiciona com uma quebra de linha