# Somar todos os valores da ta tabela

Tags: php

Estou tentando somar todos os valores de uma vez da tabela, mas está dando erro, meu codigo: `mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT SUM(entrada) FROM livro");` creio que seja porque os valores estão com virgula (ex: 1,10), alguém tem alguma dica do que se fazer? Tabela: livro, coluna: entrada.

Comment: E como está com vírgula no banco? Você armazenou um valor numérico em uma coluna de texto?

Comment: Coloquei o valor no `varchar`

Comment: Então, se possível, já refatora o banco e armazena em uma coluna numérica para não acontecer esses problemas.

Comment: Já que tem virgulas coloquei em decimal, mas ainda me retorna isto:  "Recoverable fatal error. Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\livro\index.php"  on line 2